# Transfering from python 2 to python 3 sockets

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

So I a python file where everything was written in python 2, however I needed to change it to python 3. I did so with all the strings, but I keep getting a error.
'''

```
    '''
client number 2
'''
import os
from socket import *
host = "My Ip..." # set to IP address of target computer
port = 13000
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    data = input("Enter message to send or type 'exit': ")
    UDPSock.sendto(data, addr)
    if data == ("exit"):
        break
UDPSock.close()
os._exit(0)
```

The error I get is

```
 UDPSock.sendto(bytes(data),"utf8", addr)
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

I tried doing something like

```
UDPSock.sendto(encode.(data),addr)
```

But that just printed that encode is undefined

Thank you for answers you have. Please make thorough answers because I don't quite understand sockets 100%

Comment: I think you should use `data.encode` be cause in python 3 data transfers just in binary mode

Comment: I did that but now it comes up with    UDPSock.sendto(data.encode),"utf8", addr)
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: I put paranthesis at the end but now I get   UDPSock.sendto(data.encode(),"utf8", addr)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: Not sure on the difference between UDP and TCP. I just use TCP. It looks like this...
msg = bytes.fromhex('50 FF 4C')
socket.sendall(msg)

For a string I think you'd use bytes(strToConvert, "UTF8")

Comment: To expand on @Cameron's comment, the "utf8" should be an argument to `encode` *not* an argument to `sendto`. So move it inside the parentheses. More generally, if you're having trouble getting something to work, it helps to break it into separate smaller pieces that you can troubleshoot independently: first do the encode: `bdata = data.encode("utf8")` *then* do the send: `UDPSock.sendto(bdata, addr)`  (You can always put it back together into a single statement after you figure out how it's supposed to work.)